# How to handle BLOB/TEXT on QTableView using SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, qt5

I am designing a major user interface with several fields and functions. However in order to shrink the problem I created a small application with 4 columns: name, image, dataDatabase, dateTime.

I have a MainWindow with a QTableView, as soon as I right click inside the QTableView an AddItemDialog opens up with:

1) nameLineEdit

2) ImLineEdit

3) imageLineEdit - it contains the path of the image

4) dateTimeEdit

The small minimal example is also possible to see here: Notice that I am using a menu to erase/add records

[image: GUI]

The issue I have is that I don't necessarily want to save the image (BLOB) on the QTableView and if that happens I would like for that column to accept the TEXT "No Image", but if, during the storage of images, the user decides to go back and save the image it is possible to do that.

So to provide also a visual understanding see the error I get when I try not to save the image:

[image: error message]

**What I tried so far:**

The idea (and possible solution I was trying to implement) is to create a functions that updates the row, but it is not working :

```
bool dataBase::updateItem(const Item &item)
{
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare(" UPDATE Fish_Table SET " \
    " name = ?, image = ?, dataDataBase = ?, dateTime = ?");

    q.addBindValue(item.name());
    q.addBindValue(item.image());
    q.addBindValue(item.imagesData());
    q.addBindValue(item.dateTime());
}
```

**Code of the Minimal Application is Shown Below:**

I am including the most important parts of the application below with the related description of the procedure I followed:

I created an Item with the fields **item.h**:

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item(const double dateTime,
         const QString &name = "", const QString &image = "",
         const QByteArray &imagesData = QByteArray());
    QString name() const { return mName; }
    QString image() const { return mImage; }
    QByteArray imagesData() const { return mImagesData; }
    double dateTime() const { return mDateTime; }
private:
    QString mName;
    QString mImage;
    QByteArray mImagesData;
    double mDateTime;
};
```

and its related **item.cpp**

```
Item::Item(const double dateTime,
           const QString &name, const QString &image,
           const QByteArray &imagesData)
{
    mName = name;
    mImage = image;
    mImagesData = imagesData;
    mDateTime = dateTime;
}
```

I created a **database.h** table that will contain the parameters as follows:

```
class dataBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit dataBase(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool inizializationDataBase(const QString &nameDataBase);
    bool configureDataBase();
    QString getError() const { return mError; }
    bool addItem(const Item &item);
private:
    QSqlDatabase mDatabase;
    QString mError;
};
```

And its related **database.cpp** file - I am only including the most important piece of the code for this file:

```
#define CREATE_TABLE \
     " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fish_Table" \
     " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
     ", name TEXT NOT NULL" \
     ", image TEXT NOT NULL" \
     ", dataDataBase BLOB NOT NULL" \
     ", dateTime DOUBLE NOT NULL)"

dataBase::dataBase(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

bool dataBase::inizializationDataBase(const QString &nameDataBase) {
    // code
}

bool dataBase::addItem(const Item &item) {
    QSqlQuery q;
    q.prepare("INSERT INTO Fish_Table (name, image, dataDatabase, dateTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    q.addBindValue(item.name());
    q.addBindValue(item.image());
    q.addBindValue(item.imagesData());
    q.addBindValue(item.dateTime());
    bool ok = q.exec();
    if (!ok) {
        mError = q.lastError().text();
    }
    return ok;
}
```

and finally the **AddItemDialog.cpp** that contains the fields I am trying to pass to the QTableView of the MainWindow.

```
AddItemDialog::AddItemDialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::AddItemDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    auto fileSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    fileSystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());
    ui->imageLineEdit->setCompleter(new QCompleter(fileSystemModel,this));
    QDateTime dateTime;
    dateTime.setDate(QDate::currentDate());
}

AddItemDialog::~AddItemDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void AddItemDialog::on_toolButton_clicked()
{
    auto nameDataBase = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open Images", QDir::rootPath(),
                  "Images (*.png *.jpg *jpeg *.tif *.tiff);;Any type (*.*)");
    ui->imageLineEdit->setText(nameDataBase);
}

void AddItemDialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    QFile dataBase(ui->imageLineEdit->text());
    if (!dataBase.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", dataBase.errorString());
        return;
    }
    mItem = Item(ui->nameLineEdit->text(),
                 ui->ImLineEdit->text(),dataBase.readAll());
    dataBase.close();
    accept();
}
```

**Expected result:** If the user decides to save the image no problem, but if the user decides not to save the image, then it should appear the TEXT "No Image " in the cell of the image, how to handle this exception in SQLITE/QT? 
See below the correct way I am trying to achieve:

[image: Expected]

**Actual result:** I can only save the image. If I don't I receive error.

Thanks to shed light on this.